# May one declare someone to be the messiah?

Tags: messiah, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, bar-kochba

I recall a gemarah (possibly Yerushalmi Taanit?) wherein Rebbi Akiva is quoted as proclaiming that Shimon bar Kosiba was the king Moshiach. I further understand that this statement could be one of belief as opposed to halacha or fact. I would like to know if there is any restriction for someone to publicly proclaim whether as belief or fact, that  another person is the messiah.

Comment: Try not to be wrong

Comment: Why should it be different than proclaiming anything else?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40421/was-bar-kochba-a-king/40509

Comment: you'd face opposition from the (presumably majority) naysayers who disagreed with your assessment, but there's no proscribed repercussions for making such a declaration ***provided that upon proof of being wrong you recant***, otherwise, you might be liable for a number of possible sins, such as lo tisgodedu...

Comment: There evidently was plenty of opposition to R Akiva's proclamation even at that time - "Grass will be growing in your cheeks, etc"....

Answer (score 1):

The Reason that the Rambam writes laws about it is in order to know who
Moshiach is during the time of exile (since after MOSHIACH comes it will be  obvious who he is)

To answer your question simply- if he fits the Rambams   Specifications  Then yes you could say he is chezkas Moshiach

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Comment: You should give the details as to what the Rambam says and where.

Comment: Welcome to MY! Would you mind [editing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/88875/edit) the Rambam’s discussion from Melachim 12 that you quote into this post, for future readers’ reference? Thanks, and hope to see you around!