# When Rebbe Akiva anointed Shimon Bar Kochba as Messiah, what would that ceremony have looked like?

Tags: bar-kochba

I am studying the early post-second temple period, and I am curious as to what sort of ceremony Rebbe Akiva would have performed when he decided to anoint Shimon Bar Kochba (at that time, to the best of his understanding) as Moschiach.

Was he just anointed King of Israel or was he actually proclaimed Moschiach?

Opinions seem to vary on this subject.

Comment: Keep in mind during your research that in Rabbinic Literature Bar Kochba is known as "Bar Koziba" ("son of a lie"). This refers to his status as a failed messiah. Good luck!

Comment: His coins and lead weights and letters refer to him as "Nasi" Prince, not King.  If he was anointed King, he would have advertised it.

Comment: It says somewhere he anointed him, or just assumed he was the messiah?

Comment: related to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40421/was-bar-kochba-a-king/40571

Comment: Hi, he was only referred to as "Bar Koziba *after* he had lost the approval of the rabbis. Akiva is generally credited/blamed for anointing him. 

So he would have been appointed "Nasi", so not 'King', hench not Moschiach. 

Thanks guys!